# how to automatically list folder contents inside web server on a webpage

Tags: php, javascript, file, download, webserver

i have a program that can upload a file to a specific folder on my webserver, what i want to do now is for the user to gain access to that file automatically, so after he uploads the file it will be listed on a webpage , and it will be available for download. is there anyway for this to be possible? any javascript or php will do as long as the results are met, thank you in advance.

i want to have the webpage automatically list the contents of the folder where the user uploaded the files so that they can download it. I don't want an index, but an actual list inside a webpage. just like when you upload files to google docs, and then it will automatically be listed afterwards for download.

Comment: The index that the user sees when they go to a folder that allows indexing *is* a web page. Can you be more specific about what you do and don't want them to see?

Comment: a webpage that will automatically list the content of the folder

Comment: See the Directory Functions in the [PHP Manual](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ref.dir.php)

Answer (score 0):

Store the file paths of all uploaded files in a database. You can get the list of all uploaded files for the user with ajax and display them in real time. I believe Google uses ajax to accomplish what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use something like [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php). Bear in mind the directory you pass it should be an absolute server path, and this is different from your www root that will be used to form the actual page link.

So if you have an index.php and a /images/ directory next to it, you would need something like:

```
$images_directory = "/images/";
$path_to_files = dirname(__FILE__) . $images_directory;

$dir_contents = scandir( $path_to_files );
```

You would probably then want to filter the directory contents to only display images:

```
$images = preg_grep("/(?i).(gif|jpg|png)$/", $dir_contents);
```

Now that you have an array of images, you simply need to format your html links:

```
foreach( $images as $image ){
    $file = $image_directory . $image;
    echo "<a href='$file'>$image</a>";
}
```

All that said, this is a very blind way to go about it. It's certainly useful in some situations, but if you want to do something like limiting images by user, and saving image information like name/description/tags, you may want to simply save the directory in a database when it is uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

When you are uploading a file save the path and file name in the database. And after successful upload get the file name through ajax and show the files and when he/she download it take the file name and path from db and search in the directory if found then download it to the client machine.